# Error when setting 'innerHTML' within xmlHttp.onreadystatechange function

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to write a JavaScript function changes the innerHTML of a paragraph from within an xmlHttp.onreadystatechange function. However the Chrome Console gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange (myfile.html:20)
    at myfile.html:25
```

Two things are funny about this:
1) It seems to work (the innerHTL is changed)
2) The error only shows, when I change TWO elements.

Once I comment out either one of the "document.getElementById"-lines everything seems to be working fine.

I'm stuck here. If anyone has any pointers as to what may be the problem that would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the full HTML Code (except the url variable which I have changed):

```js
var url = "https://google.com"; // original URL replaced

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

// create XMLHttpRequest object
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)

    // this only works if one of the two following lines is removed
    document.getElementById('id_hello1').innerHTML = "hello1";
  document.getElementById('id_hello2').innerHTML = "hello2";

};

// open URL
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);

// send request
xmlHttp.send();
```

```html
<h1>Hello1</h1>
<p id="id_hello1">loading...</p>
<h1>Hello2</h1>
<p id="id_hello2">loading...</p>
```

Comment: `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` means getElementById did not find the element

Comment: That Ajax code should either be after the elements or be called on document ready.

Comment: But that seems to be not true - It's working, i.e. changing the innerHTML. Also, why only if the innerHTML is changed twice, and not if only once?

Comment: "That Ajax code should either be after the elements or be called on document ready." --> It's called on readyState == 4

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using minus the url being different? Your code does have a bug in it.

Comment: my comment has nothing to do about the readystatechange, it has to do with the order the code is executed and it is possible that your Ajax code could return before the elements on the page are ready. (Probably not in this case, but it could happen)

Comment: The 2 lines after the if statement should be surrounded by brackets

Comment: @Gerard was about to say that the second time I looked at the code. lol And my comment about it should be after the element or document.ready applies because it is being executed before the element is there, hence this error.

Comment: Ok that's embarssing... Yes, the missing curly braces are to blame! Thanks @Gerard! Do you want to post that as an answer so I can set it as the corerct answer?

Comment: @Sebastian Nah, not going to post that.

Comment: @Sebastian And since the code ran right away, it did not find the element. Hence the error. That is my point, if readyState is 4 very quickly, it too has the chance that it will not find the element. Hence why adding the script after the element or calling it on document ready is important.

Comment: @epascarello, thanks for your remark., that's very helpful as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gerard posted in a comment, the problem here is that there are missing curly braces in the JS if statement. Embarrassing...